# How do you version code in Android without compiler warnings?

Tags: android

Google's docs say to use this kind of code to ensure new code is not executed on old platforms:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

But when I do that, Eclipse still gives me warnings: "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7)". What I want is to have my minimum version set to something lower than Honeycomb, have the above conditional statement protect me from running new code on old devices, and *not* have compiler warnings.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `@TargetApi(11)` before method.

Comment: For other folks reading this, @TargetApi seems a good place to start: add an import for android.annotation.TargetApi, then you can put @TargetApi(11) at the top of methods that target that version. Google's docs imply that you can put this inside conditional statements (http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck), which is what I was asking about, but when I try that I get "The annotation TargetApi is disallowed for this location."

Comment: Do you have the latest ADT plugin?

Comment: Yes; this is a new machine and I only set up the SDK/Eclipse/ADT on Monday. @TargetApi works fine at the top of methods, just not inside the conditional statement.

Comment: You can add the annotation to the method or to the class, but as you said, you cannot add it directly before a statement.

Answer (score 2):

`@TargetApi()` seems to be the best way to do this, 
Look up this [page](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck)

Answer (score 1):

Java Annotations can only be applied to [declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29) and not to [statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29). The example in the [lint documentation](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) is cheating by beginning the `if` block with a variable declaration.